# Why did the man kill himself and what happened?

Tags: lateral-thinking

> A man came home drunk, turned off the lights and went to sleep. When
>   he woke up and looked out of the window, then he saw numerous dead
>   bodies outside. In despair, the man killed himself.

Why did the man kill himself and what happened?

Comment: perhaps a similar one/ dupe of http://www.rinkworks.com/brainfood/s/latreal40.shtml. Having said this, both this question and all answers it receives may get down voted !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The man is a Lighthouse keeper: he turns off the lighthouse

So

> A lot of ships sink of his fault

Answer (score 1):

Going to go with a more general and obvious idea here - the man managed to *identify the cause of death of those outside, and decided that suicide is preferable*. There are some criterias for these:

- The cause of death must be more gruesome than suicide.
- The cause of death must be slow enough that people noticed, and went out of their house in attempt to escape (he did not notice because he blacked out).
- But it also must be quick enough that there are those who failed and died midway.
- The cause of death is as powerful as a force of nature, deterring any ideas of resistance
- The house is a deterrence to this cause of death, but it will fail sooner or later. Most likely sooner, voiding any possibility of rescue.
- On top of the previous point, escape is not an option.

Unfortunately I'm unable to come up with actual scenarios that are plausible enough, or aren't too comical.

Perhaps a volcano nearby erupted and engulfed the city with lava? Or maybe he saw some sort of new bio weapon (some kind of smoke, perhaps) that caused people outside to profusely bleed and painfully die? A zombie outbreak? Lots of possibilities.

Edit: Aw man, I posted this before I saw Mea Culpa Nay's comment. Now I feel dumb.

Comment: To be fair, your next-to-last point is almost on target.  The house *was* a deterrent to the cause of death (light vs rocks), although the problem wasn't its eventual failure.